Efficient way to compute RBF kernel matrix after linear transformation
I have a dataset of points $\{\mathbf{x}_i | \mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ and a linear transformation matrix $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, such that $\mathbf{y}_i = \mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{x}_i$, with $\mathbf{y}_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ $m<n$.
The matrix $\mathbf{F}$ is learnable, possibly with constraints such as having each column have unit norm, and/or having columns be orthogonal. I want to compute the radial basis function kernel matrix on the points $\mathbf{y}_i$, that is, for each $i,j$, compute $\exp\left(\|\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{y}_j\|^2\right/2\sigma^2)$.
Since $\mathbf{F}$ gets updated, I want to know whether there is some efficient way of re-computing or approximating the distances $\|\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{y}_j\|^2$ after each $\mathbf{F}$ update.
